# Multiple windows styles

Tags: c++, winapi

Until now I have done console programming with C++ so I'm new to window programming and, it may sound like a stupid question but how do I use multiple window styles or extended window styles in a C++ Win32 App.? Let's say i want to use WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP, WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR and WS_HSCROLL all in the same window.

Sorry if I haven't made myself clear or bad grammar.

Comment: You could only ask this question if you've never read Petzold's "Programming Windows".  That's required reading.

Comment: Also must not have read [the most basic examples in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This flags can be combined by using the binary-or operator like this (if that is what you mean):

```
WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use extended window styles you need to call [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) (vs. [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx)). Window styles - like all other flags - can be combined using the [Bitwise Inclusive OR Operator: |](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edc0fscw.aspx)

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP | WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR,
                           ...,
                           WS_HSCROLL,
                           ...);
```